# Poor performance of Array.map(f: A => B) in Scala

Tags: arrays, performance, scala, dictionary, for-loop

Please can someone explain to me, why Array.map(f: A=> B) method is implemented in a such way that it is more than 5 times slower than this code:

```
val list = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
val newList = new Array[Int](size)

var j = 0  
while (j < size) {
  newList(j) = list(j)
  j += 1
}
```

The method map(f: A=> B) in the Array class, which is provided by TraversableLike trait, uses Scala 'for loop' for iterating over the elements of input Array object, which of course is much slower than using 'while loop'.

Scala version: 2.9.2
Java: jdk1.6.0_23 64bit windows

Comment: so what you are saying is that the code above is faster than `val newList = list.map(x => x)`?

Comment: You can try: http://code.google.com/p/scalacl/wiki/ScalaCLPlugin

Comment: I'd like to see how you measured that. Did you use a micro benchmark framework like caliper?

Comment: map over Array will build ArraySeq and then copy the result to a new array

Answer (score 14):

`map` is a generic operation (and not specialized (yet)).  So you have to box/unbox the operations on the way in and out of the function.  Unsurprisingly, it's much slower.  This, rather than the style of loop used, is the culprit.

The reason it's done this way is for consistency and ease of maintenance of the code.  With infinite numbers of infinitely carefully people working on the code, each method would be hand-crafted for optimal speed while still being generic.  Generic utility has been favored over speed, as you can always get speed back by writing the while loop by hand, but if it's not generic and you need it to be, you're stuck.

Improving the performance of Scala with operations on primitive collections is a goal, but probably not the very top goal of the team working on Scala.  For now, if you need speed, use the while loop.

Comment: Though operations on arrays should be the very first thing to optimize, since performance is the only reason to use arrays (well, or size constraints).

Comment: @ziggystar - Or Java interoperability.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. Nice Collection API including map, filter, reduce methods, was one of the main features, which attracted me to Scala in the first instance. However, since I started working on some highly computing intensive inference algorithms in Bayesian Networks, I'm basically rewriting functional-like code to be more imperative.

Comment: @user1763278 - Whether you use functional or imperative styles is a different issue--that also can be a performance gain (in addition to generic vs. primitive operations).  But either way, refactoring the most computationally intensive part of your computation to be less like idiomatic Scala and more like performance-conscious Java is something I do a lot of.  Just remember that you only need to give this treatment to the core of the algorithm--the rest of your program can take full advantage of nice collections, etc..